# chrome input time not change to seccond when use only minute or hours

Tags: javascript

I have this JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#short_time').on('input', function() {

    var hours, minutes, seconds;
    var czas = document.getElementById("short_time").value; 
      [hours, minutes, seconds] = czas.split(':');
      console.log (hours, minutes, seconds);

      var time_sec;
      time_sec = hours * (60 * 60) + minutes * 60 + seconds * 1;
      console.log (time_sec);

      if(isNaN(time_sec)){
        time_sec = "720"
      }

      var change = $("input[name='time_sec']");
      change.val(time_sec);


  });

});
```

to change input type time to seconds.

I have a problem when I use Google Chrome or Internet Exploler. If `isset` only minute or hours doesn`t change to seconds when I add seconds. Why?

Comment: Use a time library. See [Tom Scott's video on Computerphile: Time & Timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)

Answer (score 0):

at least chrome doesn't give seconds in value of ... so try adding:

```
seconds = seconds || 0;
```

after initializing hours, minutes and seconds ;)

Comment: im try
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#short_time').on('input', function() {

    var hours, minutes, seconds;
    var czas = document.getElementById("short_time").value; 
      [hours, minutes, seconds] = czas.split(':');
      console.log (hours, minutes, seconds);

      if (seconds = seconds || 0) {
        seconds = 0
      }

      var time_sec;
      time_sec = hours * (60 * 60) + minutes * 60 + seconds * 1;
      console.log (time_sec);

  });

});
maybe a confirmation how to make it please
?